# How to disable test goal for lifecycle package in maven 3?

Tags: maven, maven-3

In a "dev" profile i would like to disable the test phase when executing package phase.

I have not found a way to do this in maven yet. I am using maven 3.x

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does `mvn -P dev -DskipTests package` address your requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Converting the comment to answer...

```
mvn -P dev -DskipTests package
```